# Update in one setState property causes another property change automatically in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have one table in parent component and form fields in child component. I am passing onchange function as props to receive values changed on the child component in parent and assigning the value to state property. But while change in the particular setState property causes change in another setState property automatically. Attached sample code for reference.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import _ from 'lodash';

    state = {
            activeLanguage: localStorage.selectedLanguage,
            obj1: {},
            obj2: []
        };

        componentDidMount = () => {
            this.setState({
                obj1: this.fetchUserDetails()[0],
                obj2: this.fetchUserDetails()

            });
        }

        fetchUserDetails = () => {
            const tempUserTable = [];
            const userInfo = {
                primaryAddress: {
                    addressLine1: 'Test',
                    addressLine2: 'Test',
                    city: 'Test'
                }
            };
            tempUserTable.push(userInfo);
            return tempUserTable;
        }

    handleChange = (value, path) => {
        const { obj1, obj2 } = this.state;
        console.log('Before set method:: ' + obj2);
        //obj1 primaryAddress.addressLine1 value changed from 'Test' to 'Testchange' after next line invoked
        _.set(obj1, path, value); 
        //obj2 primaryAddress.addressLine1 value changed from 'Test' to 'Testchange' automatically
        console.log('After set method:: ' + obj2); 
        this.setState({
            obj1
        });
    };
```

For example, I am receiving value, path from child component in onChange function to update the obj1 using setState. It causes change in obj2 automatically.

**Example value change happened at runtime.**

addressLine1 of obj1 field value changes from 'Test' to 'Testchange' - (value='Testchange', path='primaryAddress.addressLine1') - onChange called in parent and setState of obj1 
invoked.
addressLine1 of obj2 field value changes from 'Test' to 'Testchange' - This is happened automatically without calling setState for this obj2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any info required further.

Comment: From the [Lodash documenation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set): `"Note: This method mutates object."` I'm not sure what are you trying to do but do not mutate your state in anyway.

Comment: I m not directly setting values in this.state. Just used lodash library to set the value in the path of the object. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: why u setting state in componentDidMount ?? you should not set state there. Use constructor for that

Comment: I mean if you change the object with lodash's set method then it changes the object, whether you change it with setState or not. This is a mutation. I'm not the one provided the answer. If you couldn't find the solution yet, you can create a minimal sandbox at codesandbox.com, so we can investigate the problem.

Comment: Thanks again. I have changed my code by using clone deep before changing object directly. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're doing your data fetching outside of this sample code, but my guess is this is happening because of the way you're setting `obj1` and `obj2`. `obj1` and `obj2[0]` may actually be pointing to the same space in memory. Unlike primitives like numbers and strings, objects and arrays are treated like pointers in JS.

To get around this, we'll need to clone `obj2[0]` into its own value. Since you're already using Lodash, one option is using their `clonedeep` method. Something like this may solve your problem:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  const data = this.fetchUserDetails();
  this.setState({
    obj1: _.clonedeep(data[0]),
    obj2: data
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried your way mentioned in your comment. Still the obj2 value is getting changed when i set value in obj1. Not sure what causes the issue.

Comment: I have used your way and everywhere I have used clone deep object instead of changing it directly. It works fine. Thanks again.